# Eclipse cdt does not debug on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gdb

I am using Eclipse CDT Kepler. I Try to debug my c++ source code in my project. I am working in Ubuntu 14.04 environment and I try to produce a binary to work on my local pc (is not a cross development application).

When I launch debug right click on my project -> Debug as -> Local C/C++ application my debugger comes and stops at the begining of main function (that is fine). Then when I click step over or step into to proceed in code, Eclipse Quits from the code.

```
The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Quit
```

My code is something as follows:

```
#define TEST
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

#ifdef TEST

    printf("This is \r\n");
    printf("A test \r\n");
    printf("Of \r\n");
    printf("Eclipse CDT debug \r\n");

    measureRecorderPerformance();
 ...
```

I also tried my code using gdb from the terminal:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/fercis/workspace_eo/recorder/Executable/videorecorder 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
This is 
A test 
Of 
Eclipse CDT debug 
Test 150 frames can be written to file in 0.016187 miliseconds 
[Inferior 1 (process 6209) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

So when running in command line, gdb works fine.

The problem is probably about a setting in Eclipse, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint after main? i.e inside somewhere in the main() ?

Comment: Yes, I tried setting breakpoint inside main (actually to the all printf statements above)

Comment: Have you selected the executable properly as laid out in this page : http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_debug_exes.htm&cp=11_3_5_1_1

Comment: Yes, I tried all of the written operations, It created a new project Debug_<myProjectName> as well as a new Launch configuration. I opened up the configuration and clicked "Debug" button but the result is the same : (

Comment: There could be a problem with debugger selection as well. Did you set GDB as your default debugger? as explained in http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_run_dbg.htm

Comment: If you try a simple Hello World program, does eclipse/gdb work OK?

Comment: VISWA KSP : Yes actually gdb is selected as debugger and I tried also /usr/bin/gdb.
Mark Plotnick: I tried another project and it works? I am confused. I tried to copy all my sources in my main project to another new project and that does not work also :(

Comment: See if you can make a small, complete program that demonstrates the problem, and add it to your question.

Comment: Eclipse quits from the code? This means it closes/crashes or just your program terminates? In your workspace directory your should find .metadata/.log file that should contain useful information. BTW: what does command line gdb do if you do "start, step, step, step..." instead of just "run"? Was your code built without optimization?

Comment: How did you created c++ project?Which template did you used in c++ project creation wizard while creating project.